Movie about a old guy who's an assassin/hitman with glasses and silenced pistol
Basically I remember there being an old guy with glasses and having a silenced pistol. He's an assassin/hitman who in an apartment building kills a bunch of guys, one of the kills he hears him and shoots him through the wall. I believe he also ends up getting shot, not sure if he dies. Also possibly trying to save a kid.
This is taken from someone else's remembering of the movie: 

I remember only this scene where an assassin wearing specs kills some goons sent to murder a boy. he tells the boy to hide and begins killing all the killers one by one. he also wipes his specs once. he is wearing a white shirt, waistcoat and trousers. In one sequence he hears the board from the wooden flooring creak and finds the opponent's position and kills him. any idea? I'm sorry, this is the only scene i remember. no actors, not movie name, no year, no music, no story, I know nothing else.


I have been searching for the movie for ages (years) and literally after posting this question I found it :P It's Revolver. This is the scene in question:



